# Python Regex to extract Location and Timestamp from string

Tags: python, regex

I am a complete newbie to Python and after any help possible. Below is sample text string which I am trying to extract 2 substrings:

1. Location
2. Timestamp

Sample text:  **Your booking at Crown Street - June 29th, 1:00pm**

The *Location* substring is between the following 2 phrases were are constant "Your booking at " and " -". The spaces includes in the phrases are deliberate. In this example, my required output string is **Crown Street**. What is the best Python regex to deliver this outcome?

The *Timestamp* substring procedes "- " expression in the string. In this example, my required output string is **June 29th, 1:00pm**. What is the best Python regex to deliver this outcome?

Comment: Can you post what you have attempted?

Comment: I am new so just trying various cut & paste ideas from Google.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

example = 'Your booking at Crown Street - June 29th, 1:00pm'
regex = re.compile(r'Your booking at (?P<location>.+) - (?P<timestamp>.+)$')
print(regex.match(example).groupdict())
```

outputs

```
{'location': 'Crown Street', 'timestamp': 'June 29th, 1:00pm'}
```

Notice that this could end up in a false match if there's a `-` in the name of the location; if you're always sure there'll be an English month to start the timestamp, you could use `(?P<timestamp>(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|...).+)`.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified. I need two regex to extract location and timestamp separately, not one regex. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Does it matter? You could just discard the value you don't need at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Using `re.search`

**Demo:**

```
import re
text = "Your booking at Crown Street - June 29th, 1:00pm"

data = re.search("Your booking at\s+(.*)\s+\-\s+(.*)", text)
if data:
    print(data.group(1))
    print(data.group(2))
```

**Output:**

```
Crown Street
June 29th, 1:00pm
```

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified. I need two regex to extract location and timestamp separately, not one regex. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks @Rakesh for your response which has worked well. Is there a way to alter the regex to limit output to location only i.e. "Crown Street" using the example as a reference.

Comment: `data = re.search("Your booking at\s+(.*?)\s+\-", text)  if data:
    print(data.group(1))` ?

Comment: Please accept any one of the ans that helped you. Thanks